# Laravel route is forcing me to use a /doube/route and not /single

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I've having a weird issue than I don't fully understand...

Here is my route:

```
Route::get('/app/signin', array( 'as' => 'account-login', 'uses' => 'AccountController@getLogin' ));
```

Which works great. However, when I loose the /app part I get an error. If I change it to

```
Route::get('/signin', array( 'as' => 'account-login', 'uses' => 'AccountController@getLogin' ));
```

I get the following error:

```
 * @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException
     * @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
     */
    public function abort($code, $message = '', array $headers = array())
    {
        if ($code == 404)
        {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException($message);
        }
        else
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

** UPDATE 1 **

Here is my full list of routes:

```
// ALL PUBLIC ACCESS ROUTES
Route::get('/', array( 'as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@home' ));
Route::get('/{username}', array( 'as' => 'profile-user', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@user' ));


// UNAUTHENTICATED GROUP (GUEST - PUBLIC ACCESS WITH FORMS AND SIGNUP)
Route::group(array('before' => 'csrf'), function() {

    Route::post('/app/create', array( 'as' => 'account-create-post', 'uses' => 'AccountController@postCreate' ));
    Route::post('/app/login', array( 'as' => 'account-login-post', 'uses' => 'AccountController@postLogin' ));
    Route::post('/app/forgot-password', array( 'as' => 'account-forgot-password-post', 'uses' => 'AccountController@postForgotPassword' ));

});

Route::get('/app/forgot-password', array( 'as' => 'account-forgot-password', 'uses' => 'AccountController@getForgotPassword' ));
Route::get('/app/recover{code}', array( 'as' => 'account-recover', 'uses' => 'AccountController@getRecover' ));
Route::get('/app/signin', array( 'as' => 'account-login', 'uses' => 'AccountController@getLogin' ));
Route::get('/app/create', array( 'as' => 'account-create', 'uses' => 'AccountController@getCreate' ));
Route::get('/app/activate/{code}', array( 'as' => 'account-activate', 'uses' => 'AccountController@getActivate' ));


// AUTHENTICATED GROUP (WHEN USER IS LOGGED IN)
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'app', 'before' => 'auth'), function() {

    Route::group(array('before' => 'csrf'), function() {

        Route::post('/change-password', array( 'as' => 'account-change-password-post', 'uses' => 'AccountController@postChangePassword' ));

    });

    Route::get('/change-password', array( 'as' => 'account-change-password', 'uses' => 'AccountController@getChangePassword' ));
    Route::get('/signout', array( 'as' => 'account-sign-out', 'uses' => 'AccountController@getSignOut' ));

});
```

Comment: I am accessing the correct URL once I have updated/saved the changes. It's really weird because I can use anything such as /s/signin, something/signin but /sign is causing errors :/

Comment: What else would you need @delmadord? I can copy in all the routes, if that helps?

Comment: Can you add the rest of your routes to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Route::get('/{username}', array( 'as' => 'profile-user', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@user' ));
```

Is the problem, I would suggest to clarify this route with prepending something to it, or put it to the bottom of the routes, so other defined *one-word* routes get catched first with their respective controllers.

It is also advisable to insert a regular expression (modify to suit your needs)

```
Route::pattern('username', '[a-z]+')
```

before that route or  use `where` clause like this

```
Roue::get( /* username */ )->where('username', '[a-z]+');
```

This approach should be used on every route parameter, for more control over the Routes and data manipulation.

**Side note**

Prevent users to have usernames with other *one-word* routes you have, because they will not be accessible, as user @BarryWalsh suggested.

Comment: Thanks worked! Thanks. So I understand going forward what was causing that? The app I am creating has URLs such as http://domian.com/profilename so is there a better way of calling that route? I've added it to the bottom and its worked great as it is.

Comment: Curious too as would you need to prevent users for registering names that are the same the name of a route?

Comment: Thanks @delmadord - I found this after reading your answer which also helped http://www.laravel-tricks.com/tricks/routing-patterns

Comment: `Route::get('/{username}', ...` works as a "catch all" route and adding a pattern for `username` as @delmadord suggests will filter the catch all down to that which matchs `[a-z]+`

@BarryWalsh is right in saying you should validate your users username's so that they do not clash with any one-word routes that you have. `Route::getRoutes()` returns a `RouteCollection` that you can iterate over and grab your route names from - I would make a custom validator that checks the input isn't found within that list.

Comment: I thought I should also add, the routing system will attempt to match an input path to each route registered with the routing system one after the other. Therefore adding your `Route::get('/{username}', ...` route to the end of your routing config will also work unless as @BarryWalsh noted, a user has the same username as a route.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - Once the app gets a bit more developed I was going to create a list of site specific /urls that cannot get registered by users (i.e. /blog, /faq, /etc). I was going ask about the logic of doing that once I was a bit closer to implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

That does seem strange, but as a start I'd try seeing if removing the preceeding slashes from the target URI (so '/signin' becomes 'signin') fixes the issue as these aren't necessary.

Comment: This has absolutely no effect in Laravel 4.